# dock a tab from one chrome window to another

Tags: google-chrome

In google-chrome, is it possible to move a tab from one window to another?

If I pull one tab in a window, it becomes a separate window. Then it is not possible to merge this tab back to the original window or merge it into another window. It is very annoying that sometimes, the tab is just pulled out of the window accidentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

->first open the tab to be merged with in.

->then open the tab to be merged (or the one you accidently open)and then drag that downwards.

It will automatically be merged into window from step one.

I hope I am making some sense.
You can refer [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/161893/merging-windows-of-google-chrome) as well.

Comment: oh, didn't realize that it is so simple. I previously dragged the window around and it cannot be docked. Thank you